# Delphi - Updating Bar Chart on Date Inputs

Tags: sql, delphi, syntax-error

I'm trying to update my bar chart when dates are input into the text boxes and I am getting errors. I'm struggling to find a solution, so any help is appreciated. I would like it to update the dbGrid and chart, to show only the top 5 trainers for the dates input into the text boxes.

```
procedure TFTrainerChart.btnSubmitClick(Sender: TObject);
var FromDate,ToDate:TDateTime;

  begin

if AdoQuery1.Active then
    AdoQuery1.Close;

    FromDate:=strtoDateTime(txtFromDate.Text);
    ToDate:=strtoDateTime(txtToDate.Text);

     AdoQuery1.SQL.Add ( 'SELECT TOP 5 tblTrainers.Forename,');
      AdoQuery1.SQL.Add (' COUNT(tblTrainerBookings.TrainerID) AS Bookings');
      AdoQuery1.SQL.Add (' FROM tblTrainers,tblTrainerBookings') ;
      AdoQuery1.SQL.Add (' WHERE tblTrainers.TrainerID = tblTrainerBookings.TrainerID');
        AdoQuery1.SQL.Add ('AND tblTrainerBookings.DateOfBooking >= :FromDate');

      AdoQuery1.SQL.Add ('AND tblTrainerBookings.DateOfBooking <= :ToDate');

       AdoQuery1.SQL.Add ('GROUP BY tblTrainers.Forename');
       AdoQuery1.SQL.Add ('ORDER BY COUNT(tblTrainerBookings.TrainerID) DESC ');

       AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ToDate').Value := ToDate;
       AdoQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('FromDate').Value := FromDate;

       AdoQuery1.Open
```

[image: Order By syntax error]

[image: My Two tables I'm querying]

```
cs:='CREATE TABLE tblTrainers('+
  'TrainerID Number, '+
  'Forename TEXT(15), '+
  'Surname TEXT(20), '+
  'Address TEXT(30), '+
  'PostCode TEXT(9), '+
  'MobileNumber TEXT(11), '+
  'Email TEXT (40))';
  ADOCommand1.CommandText := cs;
  ADOCommand1.Execute;

 cs:='CREATE INDEX idxTrainer ON tblTrainers (TrainerID) WITH PRIMARY';
 ADOCommand1.CommandText := cs;
 ADOCommand1.Execute;

cs:='CREATE TABLE tblTrainerBookings ('+
 'BookingID Number,'+
 'MemberID Number CONSTRAINT FKY_MemberID References tblMembers (MemberID),'+
 'TrainerID Number CONSTRAINT FKY_TrainerID References tblTrainers (TrainerID),'+
 'DateOfBooking Date,'+
  'TimeOfBooking Time)';
 ADOCommand1.CommandText :=cs;
 ADOCommand1.Execute;

 cs:='CREATE INDEX idxTrainerBooking ON tblTrainerBookings (BookingID) with PRIMARY';
 ADOCommand1.CommandText :=cs;
 ADOCommand1.Execute;
```

Comment: Your SQL is wrong. You're  missing a `,` after your first column. You're also using an antiquated JOIN syntax. You've not included the schema for your table (what type is the *DateOfBooking` column?). Also, why aren't you just using `BETWEEN`?

Comment: The type is TDateTime

Comment: @KenWhite i can only place 2 links but I have included my 2 tables I am querying

Comment: I can't do anything with your image, because I can't copy/paste from an image to create test data and images don't give me the column definitions. The syntax error tells you the problem is in your ORDER BY, but the SQL you've posted still contains the missing `,` that I informed you about previously.

Comment: @KenWhite i did that an i still get the same errors

Comment: As I said, I can't help you without a textual description of your table schema and textual test data. I'm not going to hand-create your tables and manually enter data based on images. Please [edit] your question to provide that information and correct your SQL statement.

Comment: @KenWhite is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I reverted your edit. You cannot substantially change the question after you've received answers to it, and that would include changing to a different error message after making changes. Your question here is about a syntax error in the ORDER BY, and that question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (SQL Server 2012, Delphi 10 Seattle):

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.Add('SELECT TOP 5 t.Forename, COUNT(b.TrainerID) AS Bookings');
ADOQuery1.Add('FROM tblTrainers t');
ADOQuery1.Add('INNER JOIN tblTrainerBookings b on b.TrainerID = t.ID');
ADOQuery1.Add('WHERE b.DateOfBooking >= :FromDate');
ADOQuery1.Add('AND b.DateOfBooking <= :ToDate');
ADOQuery1.Add('GROUP BY t.Forename');
ADOQuery1.Add('ORDER BY Bookings DESC');

FromDate := EncodeDate(2015, 12, 1);
ToDate   := EncodeDate(2015, 12, 31);
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('ToDate').Value := ToDate;
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('FromDate').Value := FromDate;

ADOQuery1.Open;
```

For databases that don't allow aliased column names in the ORDER BY, you can use the position of the column in the result set instead. The below ORDER BY is the equivalent to the one in the sample above:

```
ADOQuery1.Add('ORDER BY 2 DESC');
```

As a note, I'd change the WHERE clause to be somewhat more readable:

```
ADOQuery1.Add('WHERE b.DateOfBooking BETWEEN :FromDate AND :ToDate');
```

Comment: @jackhorse1000: And you expect me to somehow read your mind to know what that new error is???